# Symfony2 form component - date widget not working with mongodb

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

Form field declaration:
    `$builder->add('birthday', 'date', array('label' => 'Data urodzenia:', 'years' => range(date('Y'), date('Y')-100)), 'required' => false);`
Corresponding document field declaration:

```
/**
 * @ODM\Field(type="date")
 */
protected $birthday;
/**
 * Set bitrhday
 *
 * @param \DateTime $birthday
 */
public function setBirthday(\DateTime $birthday)
{
    $this->birthday = $birthday;
}

/**
 * Get bitrhday
 *
 * @return \DateTime $birthday
 */
public function getBirthday()
{
    return $this->birthday;
}
```

When I set data in form value is saved to database correctly, but widget isn`t populated with  data form database field when I visit form page after saving.

Other fields in form works as expected.

It`s sf2 bug or my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

First, birthday seems to be misspelled. `Set`**`bitrhday`** & `Get`**`bitrhday`**

Second, ODM does not support the DateTime field type. ODM only supports the field type Date. See [ODM Field Type Reference](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/index.html#doctrine-field-types-reference)

ORM, on the otherhand does support the DateTime field type. See [ORM Field Type Reference](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#doctrine-field-types-reference)